# Python process a csv file to remove unicode characters greater than 3 bytes

Tags: python, csv, unicode

I'm using Python 2.7.5 and trying to take an existing CSV file and process it to remove unicode characters that are greater than 3 bytes.  (Sending this to Mechanical Turk, and it's an Amazon restriction.)

I've tried to use the top (amazing) answer in this question ([How to filter (or replace) unicode characters that would take more than 3 bytes in UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220031/how-to-filter-or-replace-unicode-characters-that-would-take-more-than-3-bytes)).  I assume that I can just iterate through the csv row-by-row, and wherever I spot unicode characters of >3 bytes, replace them with a replacement character.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
import re

re_pattern = re.compile(u'[^\u0000-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFF]', re.UNICODE)
ifile  = open('sourcefile.csv', 'rU')
reader = csv.reader(ifile, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
ofile  = open('outputfile.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

#skip header row
next(reader, None)

for row in reader:
    writer.writerow([re_pattern.sub(u'\uFFFD', unicode(c).encode('utf8')) for c in row])

ifile.close()
ofile.close()
```

I'm currently getting this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 264: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So this does iterate properly through some rows, but stops when it gets to the strange unicode characters.

I'd really appreciate some pointers; I'm completely confused.  I've replaced 'utf8' with 'latin1' and unicode(c).encode to unicode(c).decode and I keep getting this same error.

Comment: Show us some sample input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input is still *encoded* data, not Unicode values. You'd need to *decode* to `unicode` values first, but you didn't specify an encoding to use. You then need to *encode* again back to encoded values to write back to the output CSV:

```
writer.writerow([re_pattern.sub(u'\uFFFD', unicode(c, 'utf8')).encode('utf8')
                 for c in row])
```

Your error stems from the `unicode(c)` call; without an explicit codec to use, Python falls back to the default ASCII codec.

If you use your file objects as context managers, there is no need to manually close them:

```
import csv
import re

re_pattern = re.compile(u'[^\u0000-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFF]', re.UNICODE)

def limit_to_BMP(value, patt=re_pattern):
    return patt.sub(u'\uFFFD', unicode(value, 'utf8')).encode('utf8')

with open('sourcefile.csv', 'rU') as ifile, open('outputfile.csv', 'wb') as ofile:
    reader = csv.reader(ifile, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
    writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    next(reader, None)  # header is not added to output file
    writer.writerows(map(limit_to_BMP, row) for row in reader)
```

I moved the replacement action to a separate function too, and used a generator expression to produce all rows on demand for the `writer.writerows()` function.

Comment: Awesome; once I replaced the first 'utf8' with 'latin1' (I had gotten an UnicodeDecodeError: [] invalid continuation byte error) this worked perfectly. And your explanation finally helps me connect the dots on what's going on behind the scenes. Thanks!

Comment: @JedChristiansen: If you have Latin-1 encoded data, you **cannot** ever have codepoints outside of the BMP though. All your values are limited to the first 255 characters of the Unicode standard.

Comment: @JedChristiansen: in that case you are merely recoding from Latin-1 to UTF-8 and can just use `value.decode('latin1').encode('utf8')` and be done with it.

Comment: I think the problem is that my source file is a jumbled mess of encodings. I'm getting content via an API from an application where virtually anything goes (HTML tags, and I think any kind of encoding).  For example, after processing via your code above _„ñone-click_„ù becomes _ãone-click_ã .

Comment: @JedChristiansen: garbage in, garbage out. Try to get the correct encoding for the content you get from the API as early as possible. Latin-1 just happens to work always as your input bytes are always going to be in the range 0-255. That doesn't mean it is the correct encoding for your data of course.

Comment: @JedChristiansen: `„ñone-click„ù` itself already looks like a [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake); a misinterpretation of the encoding.