# Remove "characters with encodings larger than 3 bytes" using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, byte, encode

I want to remove characters with encodings larger than 3 bytes.
Because when I upload my CSV data to Amazon Mechanical Turk system, it asks me to do it.

> Your CSV file needs to be UTF-8 encoded and cannot contain characters 
>   with encodings larger than 3 bytes. For example, some non-English 
>   characters are not allowed (learn more).

To overcome this problem,
I want to make a `filter_max3bytes` funciton to remove those characters in Python3.

```
x = 'below ð\x9f~\x83,'
y = remove_max3byes(x)  # y=="below ~,"
```

Then I will apply the function before saving it to a CSV file, which is UTF-8 encoded.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362251/python-process-a-csv-file-to-remove-unicode-characters-greater-than-3-bytes) is related my problem, but they uses python 2 and the solution did not worked for me.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean "characters with encodings *in UTF-8* larger than 3 bytes"? If not, which encoding do you mean? And do you have any code of your own to show us, any attempts at all?

Comment: I'm using UTF-8 encoding to save str to files.

Comment: 1. Nothing in your example string has a UTF-8 encoding larger than 3 bytes.  2. What do you want to do when such a character is encountered? Remove it? Replace with something else?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 2. I want to remove such characters. 1. After manually removing the characters in my example, Amazon MTurk accept my CSV file. So I think some of them are more than three bytes.

Comment: How come you have a unicode string with something like `\x9f` in it in the first place? I am asking because the error may be different from what you think it is. `'\x9f'` is *"Application Program Command"*, which is not a printable character. That may be the actual problem, rather than 3-byte limit.

Comment: @zvone Thank you. Do you know how can I remove all un-printable characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the characters in your string seems to take 3 bytes in UTF-8:

```
x = 'below ð\x9f~\x83,'
```

Anyway, the way to remove them, if there were any would be:

```
filtered_x = ''.join(char for char in x if len(char.encode('utf-8')) < 3)
```

For example (with such characters):

```
>>> x = 'abcd漢字efg'
>>> ''.join(char for char in x if len(char.encode('utf-8')) < 3)
'abcdefg'
```

---

BTW, you can verify that your original string does not have 3-byte encodings by doing the following:

```
>>> for char in 'below ð\x9f~\x83,':
...     print(char, [hex(b) for b in char.encode('utf-8')])
...
b ['0x62']
e ['0x65']
l ['0x6c']
o ['0x6f']
w ['0x77']
  ['0x20']
ð ['0xc3', '0xb0']
  ['0xc2', '0x9f']
~ ['0x7e']
  ['0xc2', '0x83']
, ['0x2c']
```

---

**EDIT: A wild guess**

I believe the OP asks the wrong question and the question is in fact whether the character is printable. I'll assume anything Python displays as `\x<number>` is not printable, so this solution should work:

```
x = 'below ð\x9f~\x83,'
filtered_x = ''.join(char for char in x if not repr(char).startswith("'\\x"))
```

Result:

```
'below ð~,'
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comment. Actually, MTurk system seems not to accept two bytes characters. (1 and 3 bytes characters are accepted)

Comment: @ywat I think you are only guessing. And incorrectly. I'm sure they support characters like `ü` and `š`, which have 2 bytes. What they don't support is probably characters which are not printable.

Comment: @ywat See my last edit. That may solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you! I'll apply this filter and try uploading.

Answer (score 1):

While indirectly stated, the website only allows characters from the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP).  That includes Unicode code points U+0000 to U+FFFF.  In UTF-8, it takes four bytes to encode anything above U+FFFF:

```
>>> '\uffff'.encode('utf8')
b'\xef\xbf\xbf'
>>> '\U00010000'.encode('utf8')
b'\xf0\x90\x80\x80'
```

This filters out Unicode code points above U+FFFF:

```
>>> test_string = 'abc马克' # emoticon is U+1F600
>>> ''.join(c for c in test_string if ord(c) < 0x10000)
'abc马克'
```

When encoded (note three bytes for each Chinese character):

```
>>> ''.join(c for c in test_string if ord(c) < 0x10000).encode('utf8')
b'abc\xe9\xa9\xac\xe5\x85\x8b'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the UTF-8 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description), characters with Unicode code points below U+0800 will use at most two bytes in the encoding. So just remove any character at or above U+0800. This code copies all characters that take at most two bytes and just leave out the other characters.

```
def remove_max3byes(x):
    return ''.join(c for c in x if ord(c) < 0x800)
```

As a comment pointed out, your example string has no characters that take more than two bytes. But this command at the REPL

```
remove_max3byes(chr(0x07ff))
```

gives

```
'\u07ff'
```

and this command

```
remove_max3byes(chr(0x0800))
```

gives

```
''
```

Both are as wanted.

Comment: Does the standard say that any character at or above U+0800 will use at least 3 bytes (equivalently, are the 1 and 2-bytes spaces all "filled")?

Comment: @wim: Yes. Did you look at the Wikipedia link I gave? I assumed that the Wikipedia article is accurate.