# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 1

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to use some python module but it gives me the following error:

```
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 1
```

I think it's because my input file contains non UTF-8 characters inside, so I want to cleanse the file before I pass it to the module.

If I want to identify non UTF-8 characters and delete them, how would I do it?? I tried googling for it, but couldn't find good answers.

Comment: Not enough information. What is your input data? It should have an identifiable encoding. You shouldn't need to guess.

Comment: I extracted text from a bunch of PDF and PPT articles using an opensource named Apache Tika.

Comment: My guess is it's one of the Windows code pages, like windows-1252. `0xa9` would be a copyright sign.

Comment: @roeland yes, that's correct. It was a copyright sign!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to decode the file as UTF-8 ignoring any errors, and then re-encoding it in UTF-8.

```
string.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore').encode('utf-8')
```

Or you could replace the characters with an appropriate sequence (which can then be removed), see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220031/how-to-filter-or-replace-unicode-characters-that-would-take-more-than-3-bytes):

```
string.decode('utf-8', errors='replace').encode('utf-8')
```

But you should really determine which encoding your data is in, and convert it appropriately. `iconv` might help.

Answer (score 1):

Either use the ignore errors option as mentioned above or try using as alternative given below:

`for line in io.open("u.item", encoding="ISO-8859-1”)`

Most of the time that I parse data from somewhere, it gets encoded in this format instead of UTF-8.