# How to suppress Warning: Incorrect string value when inserting UTF8 in Django/MySQL

Tags: mysql, django

> /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py:112: Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x8C\x9D\xF0\x9F...' for column 'text' at row 1

I understand MySQL only stores 3 byte UTF8 and not 4 byte UTF8.

I'm trying to store emojis, but I'm just not going to include them, but just the plain text.

How do I make this warning go away or not appear?

Comment: This issue is addressed fully in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220031/how-to-filter-or-replace-unicode-characters-that-would-take-more-than-3-bytes

Answer (score 2):

have you tried changing the character set and collation properties of the database tables and columns to use utf8mb4 instead of utf8 ?
Also try adding

```
'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'}
```

to your DATABASES configuration:

Comment: You need MySQL 5.5 for `utf8mb4`, but I'm using MySQL 5.1

Comment: Well, your choices are:  (1) upgrade or (2) avoid emoji.