# Regex to match all unicode character above '\uFFFF'

Tags: python, regex, unicode, ucs2

Pygame and Pyglet are both crashing when I get UCS-4 characters:

> exceptions.UnicodeError: A Unicode character above '\uFFFF' was found; not supported

How do I filter all of these characters with regex?

Answer (score 1):

Although your question asks for a regex, it is not the most appropriate tool.  You can iterate over each character in your variable use `ord(c) > 0xFFFF` to detect problematic characters.

But if you require regex, try (python3)

```
import re
r1 = re.compile("[\U00010000-\U0010FFFF]")
m1 = r1.search( "Text\u00A0\U0001FFFF" )
print (m1.group())
print (m1.start())
print (m1.end())
```

For python2, just add "u" before the strings literals (to make them unicode).

Comment: Does this handles the surrogate pairs properly?

Comment: Surrogate pairs may exist only when the unicode string is encoded (example in UTF16).  Therefore, after python has decoded them, they are represented internally as code points.  In my example `\U0001FFFF` would have to be encoded by a surrogate pair in UTF-16 (but not internally in Python).  So the answer is **yes**.  Since your question specifies UCS-4, in which all code points are represented by 32 bits, UCS-4 should not have surrogate pairs.

Comment: @RyanHope: It doesn't handle surrogates: `re.sub('[\U00010000-\U0010FFFF]', '', '\udbff\udfff') != ''`. Though (normally) you shouldn't get Unicode strings that contain surrogates. See [Python issue 18814: Add utilities to "clean" surrogate code points from strings](https://bugs.python.org/issue18814)

Answer (score 0):

The font might actually be the real issue here, so I'm not sure what good filtering with regex is going to do you. I would recommend taking a look at the **[`pygame.freetype`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html)** module, since it does not limit using code points above the range of `\uFFFF`.

> To use the pygame.freetypeEnhanced Pygame module for loading and
>   rendering computer fonts based pygame.ftfont as pygame.fontpygame
>   module for loading and rendering fonts define the enviroment variable
>   PYGAME_FREETYPE before the first import of pygamethe top level pygame
>   package. pygame.ftfont is a pygame.fontpygame module for loading and
>   rendering fonts compatible module that passes all but one of the font
>   module unit tests: it does not have the UCS-2 limitation of the
>   SDL_ttf based font module, so fails to raise an exception for a code
>   point greater than ‘uFFFF’. If pygame.freetypeEnhanced Pygame module
>   for loading and rendering computer fonts is unavailable then the
>   SDL_ttf font module will be loaded instead.

↳ http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html

Comment: If you're looking to filter using regex then this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3220210/499581

Comment: Using pygame.freetype does not appear to be a viable solution on OSX or Windows. None of the pygame binary builds include this that I have tried.