# Emoji in Merge Fields Truncated

Tags: mailchimp

I've been working on a MailChimp integration and have run into an issue where their server truncates data sent via `merge_fields` when including emoji characters. The simplest example that reproduces the behaviour is a `PUT` request to `/lists/xx/members/` with the following body:

```
{
  "email_address": "my.test@email.address",
  "status": "subscribed",
  "merge_fields": {
    "FNAME": "Ian",
    "LNAME": "CoolCat"
  }
}
```

Using the playground on their developer website, the response comes back with the `"LNAME"` set correctly to `"CoolCat"`. The issue is that when I view the data later, either via a cURL lookup or generating a campaign email, The `"LNAME"` field has been truncated to `"Cool"`, stripping the emoji and everything after it.

If anyone has a fix for this behaviour, that would be appreciated. I suspect it's just an issue with MailChimp's database (I know there have been some issues with storing emoji to certain versions of MySQL, for example).

**Edit**: In the meantime, I'm using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3220210/2708650) to simply strip out the offending non-BMP Unicode characters, but I'd really like an answer that doesn't kill my data.

Comment: Have you contacted the MailChimp support team about this? Seems like they might be able to help you more directly.

Comment: I figured I would ask here first. I'm still in the development stages, so have only had access to free features —the only support that is freely available from them is the FAQ, which doesn't address this.

Comment: [The Support section of the Getting Started Guide](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/#support) provides another support option exclusively for the API.