# Remove '\x' from string in a text file in Python

Tags: python-2.7

This is my first time posting on Stack.  I would really appreciate if someone could assist me with this.

I’m trying to remove Unicode characters (`\x3a` in my case) from a text file containing the following:

```
10\x3a00\x3a00
```

The final output is supposed to be:

```
100000
```

Basically, we are being instructed to delete all traces of `\xXX` where `X` can be any of the following: `0123456789ABCDEF`.  I tried using regular expressions as follows to delete any `\xXX`.

```
Re.sub(‘\\\x[a-fA-F0-9]{2}’,””, a)
```

Where “`a`” is a line of a text file.

When I try that, I get an error saying “`invalid \x escape`”.

I’ve been struggling with this for hours.  What’s wrong with my regular expression?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing unicode \u2026 like characters in a string in python2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321138/removing-unicode-u2026-like-characters-in-a-string-in-python2-7)

Comment: @RickMajpruz I tried the solution mentioned in that question but the output gives me 10:00:00 (not 100000).  Don't know why that is.

Answer (score 3):

The character `"\x3a"` is not a multi-byte Unicode character. It is the ASCII character `":"`. Once you have specified the string `"\x3a"`, it is stored internally as the character `":"`. Python isn't seeing any `"\"` action happening. So you can't strip out `"\x3a"` as a multi-byte Unicode because Python is only seeing single byte ASCII character `":"`.

```
$ python
>>> '\x3a' == ':'
True
>>> "10\x3a00\x3a00" == "10:00:00"
True
```

Check out the description section of the Wikipedia article on [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description). See that characters in the range `U+0000-U+007F` are encoded as a single ASCII character.

If you want to strip non-ASCII characters then do following:

```
>>> print u'R\xe9n\xe9'
Réné
>>> ''.join([x for x in u'R\xe9n\xe9' if ord(x) < 127])
u'Rn'
>>> ''.join([x for x in 'Réné' if ord(x) < 127])
'Rn'
```

If you want to retain European characters but discard Unicode characters with higher code points, then change the `127` in `ord(x) < 127` to some higher value.

The post [replace 3 byte unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220031/how-to-filter-or-replace-unicode-characters-that-would-take-more-than-3-bytes), has another approach. You can also strip out code point ranges with:

```
>>> str = u'[\uE000-\uFFFF]'
>>> len(str)
5
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(u'[\uE000-\uFFFF]', re.UNICODE)
>>> pattern.sub('?', u'ab\uFFFDcd')
u'ab?cd'
```

Notice that working with `\u` may be easier than working with `\x` for specifying characters.

On the other hand, you could have the string `"\\x3a"` which you could strip out. Of course, that string isn't actually a multi-byte Unicode character but rather 4 ASCII characters.

```
$ python
>>> print '\\x3a'
\x3a
>>> '\\x3a' == ':'
False
>>> '\\x3a' == '\\' + 'x3a'
True
>>> (len('\x3a'), len('\\x3a'))
(1, 4)
```

You can also strip out the ASCII character `":"`:

```
>>> "10:00:00".replace(":", "")
'100000'
>>> "10\x3a00\x3a00".replace(":", "")
'100000'
>>> "10\x3a00\x3a00".replace("\x3a", "")
'100000'
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
import re
tagRe = re.compile(r'\\x.*?(2)')
normalText = tagRe.sub('', myText)
```

change myText with your string

Comment: here I tried to remove them but you can change '' by whatever you want