# Set of hidden unicode characters in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode

Some hidden set of Unicode characters appear in a string which needs to be removed.

I have a very large text which is extracted from a PDF file using PyPDF2 package. Now this extracted text has a lot of issues in it (like text in tables inside PDF which were structured will appear randomly when extracted) and lots of special characters also get embedded in it (like ~~~~~~~, }}}}}}}} etc) although those texts are not present when viewed as a PDF file. I tried removing those characters using the solution described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46656104/remove-x-from-string-in-a-text-file-in-python), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078816/replace-non-ascii-characters-with-a-single-space) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321138/removing-unicode-u2026-like-characters-in-a-string-in-python2-7/15321222#15321222) link but the problem still appears

```
myText = "There is a set of hidden character here => <= but it will get printed in console"

print(myText)
```

Now I would like to have a clean text without those hidden characters.

Comment: In order to get the hidden character between => and =<, you need to edit the question and grab the entire string as StackOverflow uses some encoding mechanism which hides the special character when printed on the screen.

Comment: What was the result of doing this: `print(repr(s.encode('ascii', 'ignore')))`? (from one of the links)

Comment: This is the result
`b'There is a set of hidden character here =>\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f <= but i will get printed in console'`

Comment: Is that the only hidden character you have problems with?

Comment: Right now, yes. If this gets solved maybe I can find my way for other special characters.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes for a list of the Control characters (ASCII and Unicode). Note about C1: that are Unicode Code point not UTF-8 encoding bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character `\x7f` is the [ascii character DEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), which explains why your attempts did not work. To remove all "special" ascii characters use this code:

See here for the bytes.decode [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=decode#bytes.decode).

```
import string
a = b'There is a set of hidden character here =>\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f <= but i will get printed in console'
print(repr(a))
print(repr(''.join(i for i in a.decode('ascii', 'ignore') if i in string.printable)))
```

or this if no you don't want to import string:

```
a = b'There is a set of hidden character here =>\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f <= but i will get printed in console'
print(repr(a))
print(repr(''.join(i for i in a.decode('ascii', 'ignore') if 31 < ord(i) < 127 or i in '\r\n')))
```

Comment: It still doesn't work for me as in my case the string has a character 'b' prepended before it. I would suggest modifying your string to `a = b'There is a set of hidden character here =>\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f <= but i will get printed in console'`

Comment: @mdowes Then you have a bytestring, not a string. I updated the code to deal with that.