# Convert string with "\x" character to float

Tags: python-3.x

I'm converting strings to floats using `float(x)`.  However for some reason, one of the strings is `"71.2\x0060"`.  I've tried following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46656600/9104642), but it does not remove the bytes character

```py
>>> s = "71.2\x0060"
>>> "".join([x for x in s if ord(x) < 127])
'71.2\x0060'
```

Other methods I've tried are:

```py
>>> s.split("\\x")
['71.2\x0060']
>>> s.split("\x")
ValueError: invalid \x escape
```

I'm not sure why this string is not formatted correctly, but I'd like to get as much precision from this string and move on.

Comment: The character is `\x00`

Answer (score 0):

Going off of wim's comment, the answer might be this:

```py
>>> s.split("\x00")
['71.2', '60']
```

So I should do:

```py
>>> float(s.split("\x00")[0])
71.2
```

Comment: Join them after split: `''.join(r'71.2\x0060'.split(r'\x00'))` returns `'71.260'`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the POSIX group `\p{XDigit}` does not exist in the `re` module. To remove the hex control characters with regular expressions anyway, you can try the following.

```
impore re
re.sub(r'[\x00-\x1F]', r'', '71.2\x0060')  # or:
re.sub(r'\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}', r'', r'71.2\x0060')
```

Output:

```
'71.260'
'71.260'
```

`r` means raw. Take a look at the control characters up to hex 1F in the ASCII table: https://www.torsten-horn.de/techdocs/ascii.htm

Comment: I'm a tiny bit uncomfortable about this (just because I don't understand where the issue started), this number is from a log file in between `71.2394` and `71.2727` and every number has 4 decimal points.  It seems wrong ignoring this character and joining.  If the number was `71.260\x00`, I'd be happier with a result of `71.260`

Comment: Maybe `\x00` means `0`? Then: `s.replace('\x00', '0')`. Otherwise you can use `r'[\x00-\x1F][0-9]*$'` in the first re.sub parameter to remove till the end - or use your split solution. :)